# Validating a entry field with negative data in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently im using selenium webdriver to automate the web application.There is a entry field which accepts only 10 characters.For negative scenario i need to fail that particular test case by trying to enter more than 10 characters. So i tried to enter 15 characters in that entry field with the help of "driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("125678910112346");"  In this case it accepts the first 10 characters and doesnt considers the remaining characters and hence the test case passes.please provide with a suitable code to fail that test case.

Comment: Does system behave in the same way when you tries this manually?

Comment: Yes.System accepts only 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the strings after enter the value.
First go to input field and enter the value, next get the entered value by webelement.getAttribute("value") you should get 10 characters and now compare the string length or the strings themselves.

The Logic can go like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("125678910112346");
string inputtext =driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).getAttribute("value");
if(inputtext.length()==10){//pass}
else{//fail}
```

Comment: Thanks.Could you please share a relevant sample code for your suggestion.